# Вывести остановки в ListView, которые находятся в xml файле

Tags: xml, android, xmlparser, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте, начал писать простенькую программку на android и столкнулся с проблемой.
Суть программы, вывести остановки в ListView, которые находятся в xml файле.
Собственно вот сам xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <buss>
        <bus number="1">
            <osts napr="pr">
                <ost ost="Троллейбусное депо"/>
                <ost ost="ул.Сибир-Гвардейцев"/>
                <ost ost="Пищевой техникум"/>
                <ost ost="Энергосбыт"/>
                <ost ost="Юбилейный киноцентр"/>
                <ost ost="ОАО 'КЭТК' "/>
            </osts>
            <osts napr="obr">
                <ost ost="ОАО 'КЭТК'"/>
                <ost ost="а\к 1237"/>
                <ost ost="ЗАО Токем"/>
                <ost ost="Промсвязьбанк"/>
                <ost ost="Универсам-1"/>
                <ost ost="Драмтеатр"/>
            </osts>
        </bus>
        <bus number="02">
            <osts napr="pr">
                <ost ost="Гагарина"/>
                <ost ost="Цирк"/>
                <ost ost="Цирк"/>
            </osts>
        </bus>
    </buss>
```

Нужно вывести остановки маршрута 1`<bus number="1">` с прямым направлением `<osts napr="pr">`.
Но у меня выводит только первую остановку "Троллейбусное депо"
Вот код программы:

```
try {
            XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.troll);

            while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
            {
                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("bus") && parser.getAttributeValue(0).equals(1)) 
                {
                    parser.next();
                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("osts") && parser.getAttributeValue(0).equals("pr") )
                    {
                        parser.next();
                        while (parser.getName().equals("ost"))
                        {
                            list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0));  
                            parser.next();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    parser.next();  
                }

            }
            parser.next();

        }
```

Comment: Узнаю Новосиб :)

Comment: У вас код SAX парсера слишком запутанный, обычно делается не так, а по другому. Как только вы входите в начало тега выставляйте булевский флаг типа `ost=true`, в конце тега сбрасывайте его. Далее уже при встрече тега `<osts>` смотрите на наличие флага `ost` и парсите содержимое тега `<osts>` результат складывайте в какой-нить `ArrayList`. В этом случае вы получите линейный код, без вложенных `if`'ов - иначе у вас получается что туча ифов, туча `parser.next()` что путает и иначе как трассировкой в отладчике ничего не поймете.

Comment: Barmaley, спасибо за идею, выручили

Answer (score 1):

Если кому нужно, вот как получилось, использовал два флага

```
 boolean flag = false;
    boolean flag1 = false;
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.troll);

        while (parser.getEventType()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
        {
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("bus") && parser.getAttributeValue(0).equals(nom)) 
            {
                flag=true;
            }

            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("osts") && parser.getAttributeValue(0).equals("pr") && flag==true )
            {
                flag=false;
                flag1=true;
            }
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getName().equals("osts") && flag1==true )
            {
                flag1=false;
            }
            if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("ost") && flag1==true)
            {
                list.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
            }

        parser.next();
        }
    }
```